# Make signed file from content file and its detached signature?

Tags: digital-signature, gnupg, openpgp

I have a text file which I will call `filename.txt`. Firstly I call

`gpg --output filename.asc --clearsign filename.txt`

Signed file `filename.asc` is created. Then I call

`gpg --armor --output filename.sig --detach-sign filename.asc`

Signature is extracted from signed file `filename.asc` and saved in `filename.sig`.

My question is if it is possible somehow to merge original unsigned file `filename.txt` and file with ASCII armored signature `filename.sig` to make signed file? I see no such functionality in GPG, but maybe I don't know something? Or maybe is it possible with others tools (Java processing or anything)?

Simply merging this files results with failed signature verification. In my use case I need to sign file, reply with signature file (without content), then I receive separate siganture and conent file. I need to merge it and encrypt. For now I am not using `--detach` switch and I just split signed file into two files and then I am simply merging them. But when I use `--detach` switch siganture changes and it doesn't work when I merge siganture file with content file. It could stay the way it is right now, but I want to extract siganture in standard way using `--detach` switch rather than just cutting signed file into pieces, but then I don't see an option to merge siganture exported with `--detach` switch

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can not simply take a detached signature and combine it with the original data to create a clear-signed message, unless you normalize the input before creating the signature.

GnuPG will pack the original input text differently, depending on the type of operation (detached vs. clear-sign). RFC4880 section 7.1 makes note of this (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-7.1).

> As with binary signatures on text documents, a cleartext signature is
> calculated on the text using canonical  line endings.  The
> line ending (i.e., the `<CR><LF>`) before the '-----BEGIN PGP
> SIGNATURE-----' line that terminates the signed text is not
> considered part of the signed text.

So, we must first normalize the line endings of the input text, then remove the final `<CR><LF>` from the end of the text.

Here is an example of how the original input data would need to be altered:

`gpg --armor --output filename.txt.asc --detach-sign <(sed 's/$/\r/' filename.txt | head -c -2)`

That will create the detached signature (filename.txt.asc) after first converting the line endings ('`$`') to a carriage-return ('`\r`'), and also remove the carriage-return + line-feed from the end of the text input.

Now you can build a clear-signed message from the signature (filename.txt.asc) and the original file (filename.txt), like so:

`gpg --verify <(echo -e "-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----\nHash: SHA1\n\n$(cat filename.txt)\n$(cat filename.txt.asc)")`

(you will have to replace the hash algorithm - `SHA1` in my example - with whatever you are actually using)

Also, it should be noted -

> `gpg --armor --output filename.sig --detach-sign filename.asc`
> Signature is extracted from signed file filename.asc and saved in filename.sig.

This does not extract any signature -- it creates a new signature of the data within the file `filename.asc` (including the original signature), and saves it to `filename.sig`.  If you pass --clearsign instead of --detach-sign you will see what I mean.

Comment: I am working on Windows so I guess I don't need to change $ to /r? Becuase Windows new line is already /r/n. And the only thing to do is to remove empty line before siganture? If so, then it doens't work for me.

Comment: And the second thing is I need to detach signature from encrypted file and do the same thing as with signature detached from signed file. Is it possible?